# How do I save a code into text files per multiple timesteps?

Tags: matlab

I am writing a simulation that analyzes the X,Y,Theta coordinates of the system. I am running the simulation by TMAX and for N particles. However, since TMAX is usually very large, I only want the data for every 100 time steps. Currently, my code gives me the information for every time step and particle position. However, it spits all the information onto one matrix, IE if I am running a 12 particle simulation for 50 steps (short for the example), the first 12 rows are particles 1-12 and their positions at time=10. However, the next 12 rows are particles 1-12 at time=20 and so on. How would I make each time step into its own text file? Below is my code:

```
fid = fopen('word.txt','w');
for nn = 1:TMAX
   if mod(nn,10)==0

    x = x + vel*cos(theta)*dt;
    y = y + vel*sin(theta)*dt;
    fprintf(fid, '%4.5f\t%4.5f\t%4.5f\n', x,y,theta);
   end
end
```

Currently, this is printing all of the data into one matrix. It goes rows 1-12 are time step one, then 13-24 are time step two. How would I be able to save each timestep into its own file, with a different name? Is there any way to make a variable file name? Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the `fopen` command inside the loop and name the files according to your variable `nn`:

```
for nn = 1:TMAX
   if mod(nn,10)==0
      fid = fopen(['word' num2str(nn) '.txt'],'w');
      x = x + vel*cos(theta)*dt;
      y = y + vel*sin(theta)*dt;
      fprintf(fid, '%4.5f\t%4.5f\t%4.5f\n', x,y,theta);
      fclose(fid)
   end
end
```